# Подскажите как можно прослушать события в NavigationView?

Tags: android

Подскажите как можно прослушать события в NavigationView? Тобишь проверить checked.

В onNavigationItemSelected не работает.

onNavigationItemSelected работает тогда когда пользователь пальцем ткнет на один из пунктов NavigationView.

А мне нужно проверить это программно. тобишь если программно отправить 
Home.navigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setChecked(true);

То как мне в NavigationView поймать тот момент когда какой - то из пунктов NavigationView меняет cheked?

---

Думаю теперь мой вопрос звучит более понятнее

Comment: Ну, наверное запустить нужную актвити с флагами типа ClearHistory или как-то так и передать через интенет к-л флаг, который в актвиити вытащить и отобразить нужное

Comment: @xTIGRx, во-первых, `NavigationDrawer` эта вьюха, которая аттачится к `Activity`.  во-вторых, вопрос не совсем понятен

Comment: @tim_taller, ну чего не понятного то? NavigationDrawer креипться к активити. Назовем его MainActivity. Также есть Активити B. Так вот если нажать на кнопку в активити B то должен открыться MainAcitvity и оттуда выбраться 2 фргамент.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вроде уже близко к цели. В navigationDrawer привязывается фрагменты. Скажите как вызвать нужный фрагмент из другого Активити?

Просто через Static у меня ничего не вышло

Comment: Не надо статик. Положите что-то в интент, которым запускаете активити. В запущенной - вытащите и в зависимотси от значения вытащенного отображайте нужное. Хоть бы и программно нажимая на элемент меню

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Я кажется понял как решить мою проблему. Подскажите как можно прослушать события в NavigationView? Тобишь проверить checked. В onNavigationItemSelected не работает. onNavigationItemSelected работает тогда когда пользователь пальцем ткнет на один из пунктов NavigationView

Comment: Не надо никаких обращений к разметке через статические константы. Всё можно сделать через onNavigationItemSelected - просто вынесите его в отдельную переменную и вызывайте на нём что-то типа `onNavigationItemSelected.onItemClicked(menuItem);`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спс создайте ответ я закрою